# iPhone action button image file available anywhere?

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I'm working on an app and want to use the image from the action type toolbar button (the one with the arrow coming from the box that we often use for share etc) in a custom button. Is there some way I can get hold of the .png for it?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is the open source UIKit artwork extractor project available at Github: https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor

Answer (score 2):

There's a mockup toolkit available for iOS SDK at http://blog.metaspark.com/2009/02/fireworks-toolkit-for-creating-iphone-ui-mockups/

Check the fourth image on right most column. I hope it contains the image you want.

You can download the mockup toolkit and open up with fireworks or photoshop to extract images from there. If you don't have these adobe softwares then the open source software GIMP is your good friend to extract the image.

Answer (score -1):

There really is no need to duplicate the image content since its already in the framework.

Have a look at this code:

```
UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(onActionButtonClicked:)];
```

The relevant portion being the [initWithBarButtonSystemItem](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBarButtonItem/initWithBarButtonSystemItem:target:action:) initialization method.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780965/iphone-app-action-button) may also be more useful in answering this question than the selected answer.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question